# Modeling Lambertian surface by using second order spherical harmonics lighting?

Tags: 3d, spherical-harmonics

For a 3D surface assumed that its surface appearance follows the Lambertian reflectance i.e. $I = \rho (\mathbb{l} \cdot \mathbb{n})$, I found that it also can be expressed by using following second-order spherical harmonics[1] :

$I=\rho \mathbb{y}^T\phi(\mathbb{n})$

where $\mathbb{y}=[y^r, y^g, y^b]$ is weight vector

and $\phi(\mathbb{n})=[1, n_x, n_y,n_z, n_xn_y, n_xn_z, n_yn_z, n_x^2-n_y^2, 3n_z^2-1]$.

I tried to google to find a theoretical base of this relationship. But no articles which are about spherical harmonics lighting have the expressions like $\phi(\mathbb{n})$. Can someone recommend a document or article about this relationship?

Thanks in advance.

[1] Ichim, Alexandru Eugen, Sofien Bouaziz, and Mark Pauly. "Dynamic 3D avatar creation from hand-held video input." ACM Transactions on Graphics (ToG) 34.4 (2015): 45.

Comment: What kind of spherical harmonics are you familiar with? These are just the [real spherical harmonics in Cartesian form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics#Real_spherical_harmonics) up to second order.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I had found a paper [Face recognition from a single training image under arbitrary unknown lighting using spherical harmonics.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1580481). Although there is no mention about this paper in [1], it has sufficient information what I need.